# JList not showing all the elements read

Tags: java, swing, jlist

everyone. I have a JList inside a JPanel, which I initialized with the following code:

```
DefaultListModel lmodel;
lmodel=new DefaultListModel();
jList1.setModel(lmodel);
```

JList was created in the Netbeans visual editor and put inside JScrollPane1. When I add or remove a few elements from the model, everything works just fine. Nevertheless, there seems to be a limit to the number of elements the JList can show, which is weirdly set at 294.

I have a method that reads items from a text file, which is pretty standard:

```
BufferedReader inputStream=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(nomeArquivo));
String line = inputStream.readLine();
while (line!=null) {
    int i=line.indexOf("=");
    if (i>0) {
       lmodel.addElement(line);                        
    }
    line = inputStream.readLine();
}         
inputStream.close();
System.out.println("Final list size="+jList1.getModel().getSize());
```

All trys and catches are in place - this is just a fragment. There is no reading error and everything goes well, with no exceptions.

When I read a file that contains 400 elements, all those 400 elements are inside the lmodel. I can even save them afterwards (there is a method for that too) and the println at the end of the method gives me the number 400 as read.

Nevertheless, the list never shows more that 294 elements. If I had a number x of elements in the list, only 294-x elements are viewed on screen.

Does anybody know what might be happening?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Perhaps you are setting [`JList.setVisibleRowCount(294)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setVisibleRowCount%28int%29) somewhere. Check Netbeans generated code. Why would you want 300+ rows to all be displayed on screen at once?

Comment: I am not setting the Visible Row Count at any place. I even tried to set it to the number of elements in the lmodel (jList1.setVisibleRowCount(jList1.getModel().getSize()+1). What I want is for the user to be deal with his list. If he wants to insert 400 elements, that is a valid usage. I do not want an artificial limitation (specially because the user was the one who detected the bug - in my tests I always worked with 10 or 20 elements!!!).

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I am sorry if you think I did not do it, Mr. Thompson, for it probably derives from the fact that I was not clear enough in my question, but all the code pertaining to the bug is above. Would you mind telling me what part of the problem you did not see included in the question?

Comment: @rlinden what Mr. Thompson want to say that we can't test any code, cause you don't post any `compilable correct example` i think.

Comment: OK, something very weird happened. I was following Mr Thopson and Mr. Nachokk suggestions on posting compilable code and started creating a new application in order to post its full code here. When I executed it, the code just worked. Hence, I deleted my JList1 and inserted an ew one into my JPanel and everything worked fine. I can swear that I di dnot change any parameter on JList1 (even the name remained that awful thing), but maybe I did, without knowing... Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Did you put your JList inside of a ScrollPane? If you have more than whats visible in the List you should be able to scroll through all 400? Try this somewhere since you didn't post all of your code up

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jList1);
```

then put the scroll pane onto the panel. Or if your using a gui editor remove your old JList and put the scrollpane on and then add the Jlist to the scroll pane. I hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, it was done. The actual JList size allows for about 30 elements to be viewed, but I can scroll and see the 294 elements.

Comment: Could you edit your code above to show all of what you've done? If you haven't limited the view of the JList and you have a JScrollPane it would be very helpful to see your code.

Comment: @rlinden "I deleted my JList1 and inserted an new one into my JPanel and everything worked fine." Glad that worked that's kinda what I meant sorry I wasn't more specific. Glad it worked for you!

Comment: For better help sooner, post an SSCCE